# iOS force landscape but not all contents are displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiinterfaceorientation

I am trying to work on iOS app , one viewController portrait , one viewController using GoogleMap landscape orientation as follows :

[image]

When it comes to the implementation and testing, it shows : 
[image]

I am not sure how it could be when running on iPhone 6 iOS 8.3 . it seems that setting device orientation and interface orientation are different parameters have to be set. I have

AppDelegate.m

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;

}
```

ViewControllerA.m

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];


}
```

ViewControllerB.m

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
      [super viewDidAppear:animated];
      isPresented = YES;

        NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
       [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:   UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];


}


viewDidLoad ...

  GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"assadsd arrived map");
    if(latitide!=0.00&&longitude!=0.00) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitide, longitude);
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(position.latitude, position.longitude);
        camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:latitide  longitude:longitude  zoom:12];
    }else{
        camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:22.2855200   longitude:114.1576900  zoom:12];
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.2855200, 114.1576900);
    }


    self.myMapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.view.bounds camera:camera];
```

Could you please tell me the know-how to work as the  first picture does ? It seems that iOS 8.3 has some orientation bug that has to re-=assign the correct view width and height but I am not sure how exactly it could work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NavigationController then create navigationController subclass and override the shouldAutorotate method.

Comment: No , I am not using  NavigationController